# False grouping of author in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have experiencing a strange error (?) with the grouping of author names in the bibliography with biblatex. With the following MWE the bibliography is OK: all references are found under "Vega y Carpio, Lope de":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{lopedevegaarte,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  title =        {Arte nuevo de hacer comedias},
  location =     {Madrid},
  year =         1609,
}

@Book{vega-obrascompletas-prosaiii,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  maintitle =    {Obras completas},
  volume =       3,
  title =        {Prosa. Epistolario, I (1604-1633)},
  location =     {Madrid},
  year =         2008,
}

@book{Vega-jerusalem,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  title =        {La Jerusalén conquistada},
  year =         1609,
  location =     {Madrid},
}

@Book{vega1997peribocana,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  title =        {Peribáñez y el comendador de Ocaña},
  year =         1997,
  editor =       {McGrady, Donald},
  introduction = {Oleza, Joan},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**BUT**: If I add the following item to the bib, the bibliography is not being grouped correctly:

```
@book{Vega-jerusalemreprint,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  title =        {La Jerusalén conquistada},
  year =         1954,
  editor =       {Entrambasaguas, Joaquín de},
  related =      {Vega-jerusalem},
  relatedtype =  {reprintof}
}
```

See the image:
[image]

Versions: Biblatex (2.6) and biber (1.6).

Comment: I assume you've tried pasting the entire author={...} from a working copy to the new one?  I'm just thinking of characters that look the same but aren't.

Comment: @ChrisH: yes, I did.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug occurring in any standard style that offers the `dashed` option. Related entries can be separated by linebreaks, so it might take some time to settle on the best solution here. As a temporary workaround, add the following to your document preamble.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretobibmacro{related}{\booltrue{bbx@inset}\let\bbx@relatedhash\bbx@lasthash}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{related}{\global\let\bbx@lasthash\bbx@relatedhash}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling your code and it seems to work fine:

```
pdflatex article.tex
biber article.bcf
pdflatex article.tex
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{lopedevegaarte,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  title =        {Arte nuevo de hacer comedias},
  location =     {Madrid},
  year =         1609,
}

@Book{vega-obrascompletas-prosaiii,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  maintitle =    {Obras completas},
  volume =       3,
  title =        {Prosa. Epistolario, I (1604-1633)},
  location =     {Madrid},
  year =         2008,
}

@book{Vega-jerusalem,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  title =        {La Jerusalén conquistada},
  year =         1609,
  location =     {Madrid},
}

@Book{vega1997peribocana,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  title =        {Peribáñez y el comendador de Ocaña},
  year =         1997,
  editor =       {McGrady, Donald},
  introduction = {Oleza, Joan},
}

@book{Vega-jerusalemreprint,
  author =       {Vega y Carpio, Félix Lope de},
  title =        {La Jerusalén conquistada},
  year =         1954,
  editor =       {Entrambasaguas, Joaquín de},
  related =      {Vega-jerusalem},
  relatedtype =  {reprintof}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image: Output]

Comment: thanks for your answer. With biblatex 2.6 in Texlive 2013 I'm still getting the same result I sent previously...

Comment: Oh, I'm using Texlive 2012... You could try removing the `related` and `relatedtype` fields in the last `bibitem`...

Comment: Just checked my version of biber, and it **Biber 1.5** ... So my guess is that there is a small bug in the newest release.

Comment: yes I can... and it works. But I would like to make use of the functionality... It seems to be a bug in biber 1.6...